# IBM Blockchain 2.0 (beta) does not detect cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-blockchain

I am trying the new IBM blockchain service on bluemix. It requires a kubernetes cluster.

Following the link provided, I created a new cluster (free tier, expires in 30 days).
My cluster is up and "running": [image]

However, getting back to the procedure of creating my blockchain service, it does not present me the new cluster (even after refreshing the page):

[image]

Checking the console does not give any error.

Is there a configuration I missed or some requirements I do not meet to create a cluster for my blockchain service?

Comment: you might want to check its at the right version level / https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain/howto?topic=blockchain-ibp-v2-deploy-iks#ibp-v2-deploy-iks. I suggest to get support through IBP's official beta support channel -> https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain?topic=blockchain-blockchain-support#blockchain-support

Comment: I checked that. It was OK. I created and deleted the cluster twice, now I've got it. Don't know why it works now and not before. (But the blockchain console is kind of buggy, cannot access an orderer pannel without waiting a few minutes and a bunch of errors inside the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and recreating a cluster worked during the third attempt. No idea why.

Update: It seems that the cluster needs to be in the same region. (If you created the blockchain on Dallas, the cluster must be created on Dallas too.)